# Validate user string input

Tags: java

Coding a simple HiLo card game where the user is given a card value from a deck of cards and then inputs 'higher', 'lower' or 'equal' trying to guess the balue of the next card.

Just really can't get my head around user input validation with iteration ie. not moving on until a string  with the required parameters has been entered.

My code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class HiLoGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randomCard = new Random();
    int numberOfSuccesses = 0;
    boolean finished = false;
    int card = (randomCard.nextInt(13) + 2);
    while (finished != true) {
        int nextCard = (randomCard.nextInt(13) + 2);
        String pictureCard = "";
        if (((numberOfSuccesses < 0) ? nextCard : card) == 11) {
            pictureCard = "Jack";
        } else if (((numberOfSuccesses < 0) ? nextCard : card) == 12) {
            pictureCard = "Queen";
        } else if (((numberOfSuccesses < 0) ? nextCard : card) == 13) {
            pictureCard = "King";
        } else if (((numberOfSuccesses < 0) ? nextCard : card) == 14) {
            pictureCard = "Ace";
        }

        System.out.println("The card is a " + ((card > 10) ? pictureCard : card));

        if (numberOfSuccesses == 4) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations. You got them all correct");
            finished = true;
            break;
        }
        while (!reader.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals("higher")
                || !reader.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals("lower")
                || !reader.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals("equal")) {
            System.out.println("Try again!");
            reader.next();
        }

        String userGuess = reader.nextLine().toLowerCase();

//TODO validate input
        if (userGuess.equals("higher")) {
            if (nextCard > card) {
                numberOfSuccesses++;
            } else {
                finished = true;
                break;
            }
        } else if (userGuess.equals("lower")) {
            if (nextCard < card) {
                numberOfSuccesses++;
            } else {
                finished = true;
                break;
            }
        } else if (userGuess.equals("equal")) {
            if (nextCard == card) {
                numberOfSuccesses++;
            } else {
                finished = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(numberOfSuccesses);
        card = nextCard;
    }
    if (numberOfSuccesses < 4) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, incorrect!");
    }
}
}
```

and the relevant code extract:

```
 while (!reader.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals("higher")
            || !reader.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals("lower")
            || !reader.nextLine().toLowerCase().equals("equal")) {
        System.out.println("Try again!");
        reader.next();
    }
```

It kinda just gets stuck at the above part giving "Try again" over and. I've completed programs having to use .hasNextInt() but I'm struggling with this string validation.

Thanks for any and all help/comments!

Comment: Evaluate each of these three sub-clauses separately, and let me know what you get.

Comment: In addition to @john3136's comment you should think about the user's input being "not higher" or "not lower" or "not equal" meaning the user needs to try again. Also that pictureCard logic is a bit strange, it only works because numberOfSuccesses can never be negative.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `reader.nextLine()` up to 3 times and so you are comparing 3 different strings.

If I enter "xxx" your code says "xxx != higher so read another line" - it never compares "xxx" to "lower" or "equal".

Also pay attention to `&&` vs `||`.

Solution is to read one line into a variable and use that variable for each condition. I'm not going to write it out as this is clearly homework or a self learning exercise, so best for you to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think your condition logic needs to change. You are checking if input not equal to "higher" or not equal to "lower" or not equal to "equal" so it will always be false overall even if you enter expected value - if you enter "higher" it's not equal to lower. You need to change ors to ands.